# Pie Chart in Excel, is it possible to have a slice for a remaining balance?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

There is a budget for each employee to use on expenses. We keep track of expenses throughout the year as it gets used. At the end of the year, a lot of these budgeted dollars do not get spent and i'd like to highlight this to the employees, while also showing the categories of where the money is being spent. 
(Categories will be used multiple times throughout the year)

Eg Data Set:

**Budget for the year: $10000**

Expenses so far:

- Registration: $400
- Flight $900
- Per Diems $200
- Hotel $400

I'm using a pivot table/graph but can't seem to figure out how to get the remaining balance into it.

Thanks for your help and time to read this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely making an additional entry for remaining expenses would be the simplest method.

But
In your example.

```
Registration: $400
Flight $900
Per Diems $200
Hotel $400
Remaining = (budget for the year) - (sum of the above expenses)
```

This would give you the value which you can then work into your pie chart

Comment: I get so into my brain that the simplest answer was right in front of me! thank you

Comment: Hehe no problem we've all been there. Glad I could help